# Submitted form via Ajax returns [object Object] in error response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

The Form:

```
<form class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-right banner-contact-form" onSubmit="return support_send();" id="contact_form" name="contact_form">

        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
            <h3>Application Form</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <select class="form-control input-md" id="title" name="title" required>
                <option value="" selected hidden>Title</option>
                <option value="1">Mr</option>
                <option value="2">Mrs</option>
                <option value="3">Miss</option>
                <option value="4">Ms</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" id="contact_name" placeholder="Your Full Name" name="contact_name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" id="post_code" placeholder="Postcode" name="post_code" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <select class="form-control input-md" id="product" name="product" required>
                <option value="" selected hidden>Main product interested in</option>
                <option value="1">Washing Machines</option>
                <option value="2">Washer Dryers</option>
                <option value="3">Tumble Dryers</option>
                <option value="4">Dishwashers</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control input-md" id="contact_telephone_number" placeholder="Contact Telephone Number" name="contact_telephone_number" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" class="form-control input-md" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default col-xs-12 btn btn-success"><span class="banner-contact-form-submit">Apply today</span><br><small>no obligation | fast response</small></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <p id="message_result" class="text-center"></p>
            <p class="text-center"><span class="banner-contact-form-apr">68.9% APR</span> representative <br /> (64.9% APR existing customers)</p>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Ajax Handler:

```
function support_send(){
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/contact_handler.php",
    data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function( response ) {
        alert("It worked");
    },
        error: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
event.preventDefault()
};
```

Php Handler:

```
<?php
$name = addslashes($_POST['title'];)
$name = addslashes($_POST['contact_name'];)
$email = addslashes($_POST['email'];)
$telephone = addslashes($_POST['contact_telephone_number'];)
$post_code = addslashes($_POST['post_code'];)
$product = addslashes($_POST['product'];)
$from = 'From: Contact Us Form'; 
$to = 'info@mmulholland.co.uk'; 
$subject = 'New Contact Enquiry';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n product:\n $product";

if (!empty($_POST)) {                
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
}
?>
```

I am trying to submit a contact form via ajax which will then be emailed to the client, my issue here is that it keeps returning an error response of [object Object].

I believe the issue is that some of the fields in the form being submitted are objects but I cant figure out how to fix this issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? This seems wrong. What makes you think `xhr.responseText` contains JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

`alert` is not a debugging tool. It converts its argument to a string. The string representation of an object is `[object Object]`:

```js
alert({value: 42}) // shows [object Object]
```

[**Use `console.log` instead.**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/console/console-write?hl=en) Also make sure to [read the documentation of the API  you are using](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). The signature of the `error` callback is

> `Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`

So you want to log the second and third argument:

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
  console.log('Status:', status);
  console.log('Error:', error);
}
```

Then you will know what the issue is and can start fixing it.

Comment: It says:Status: Error 
Error: Internal Server Error

I assume the issue is with my server itself then?

Comment: @MartinMulholland: Yes.